# Understanding weights from a convolutional layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to do semantic segmentation for magnetic resonance images, which are one channel images.

To get encoder from a U-Net network I use this function:

```
def get_encoder_unet(img_shape, k_init = 'glorot_uniform', bias_init='zeros'):

    inp = Input(shape=img_shape)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=bias_init, name='conv1_1')(inp)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=bias_init, name='conv1_2')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool1')(conv1)
    
    conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=bias_init, name='conv2_1')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=bias_init, name='conv2_2')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool2')(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=bias_init, name='conv3_1')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=bias_init, name='conv3_2')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool3')(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=bias_init, name='conv4_1')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=bias_init, name='conv4_2')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool4')(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=bias_init, name='conv5_1')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=bias_init, name='conv5_2')(conv5)

    return conv5,conv4,conv3,conv2,conv1,inp
```

And its summary is:

```
Model: "encoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 200, 200, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      1664      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      102464    
_________________________________________________________________
pool1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 100, 100, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 96)      55392     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 96)      83040     
_________________________________________________________________
pool2 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 50, 50, 96)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 128)       110720    
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
pool3 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 25, 25, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 256)       1048832   
_________________________________________________________________
pool4 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 12, 12, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808   
=================================================================
Total params: 5,384,832
Trainable params: 5,384,832
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I'm trying to understand how neural networks work, and I have this code to show the shape for the last layer weights and biases.

```
layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers])

layer_name = model.layers[-1].name
#layer_name = 'conv5_2'

filter_index = 0 # Which filter in this block would you like to visualise?

# Grab the filters and biases for that layer
filters, biases = layer_dict[layer_name].get_weights()

print("Filters")
print("\tType: ", type(filters))
print("\tShape: ", filters.shape)
print("Biases")
print("\tType: ", type(biases))
print("\tShape: ", biases.shape)
```

With this output:

```
Filters
    Type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    Shape:  (3, 3, 512, 512)
Biases
    Type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    Shape:  (512,)
```

I'm trying to understand what `Filters' shape` means `(3, 3, 512, 512)`. I think the last `512` are the number of `filters` in this layer, but what `(3, 3, 512)` means? **My images are one channel, so I don't understand that `3, 3` in the filters' shape** (`img_shape` is `(200, 200, 1)`).

Comment: Looks at it this way, consider your input is a RGB image and when you specify n number of filters of certain size. what's actually happening is n×3 filters are being used to convolve the same RGB image to produce a n channel image. This continues and holds here for 512(filters)x512(channels)

Comment: @sai I'm using one channel images and I think it is correct to have a kernel size of `(3, 3)` in the last convolutional layer `Conv2D`. I'm confuse if my code only works with 3 channel images because I don't understand why you say *"... what's actually happening is n×3 filters are being used to convolve the same RGB image to produce a n channel images"*

Comment: Your code works perfectly for 1 channel. The only reason why I choose to explain using RGB image is because it is easier to understand at the beginning. If at all over here your input was a 3 channel image, then the filter shape would be (5, 5, 3, 64), meaning 64 sets of 5x5 filters for each channel are used. Also, check this for some more details about dimensions https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the last 512 are the number of filters in this layer, but what (3, 3, 512) means?

Means overall size of filters: they are 3D themselves. As input of `conv5_2` you have [batch, height', width', channels] tensor. Filters in your case has size 3*3 per channel: you take every 3x3 region of `conv5_2` input, applying 3x3 filter to it and get 1 value as output (see [animation](https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*VVvdh-BUKFh2pwDD0kPeRA@2x.gif)). But those 3x3 filters are different for every channel (512 in your case) (see [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*BSLjlJf31gj98ABJMCt3-g@2x.png) illustration for 1 channel). After all you want perform Conv2D `number_of_filter` times, so you need 512 filters of size 3x3x512.
Good article for deeper dive into intuition behind [CNN architect](https://towardsdatascience.com/applied-deep-learning-part-4-convolutional-neural-networks-584bc134c1e2#7d8a) and Conv2D in particular (see part 2)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. There is something that I haven't understood: Why I "*... want to perform Conv2D `number_of_filter` times*"? Thanks again.

Comment: This is according to your model. Output of Conv2D called "feature maps" ([visualized](https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*A86wUjL-Z0SWDDI3slKqtg@2x.png)) - this is a way CNNs "understand" input they receive. Later if specific combination of features appears in output, last layer of CNN (fully connected for example) matches those features with particular class. For example: more feature maps - less robust network. So `number_of_filter` picked to achieve best performance (accuracy/robustness/speed) on task during model architecture implementation.

Comment: I do not have some article I would like to share. I think when you already dive into basics of ML/CNN, some particular tasks like semantic segmentation should be learned from source - models' articles. They usually disclosure some "features" like residual blocks or atrous convolutions.